# File.getdirectorylisting asynchronously

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am downloading library from server asynchronously.In its Directory_Listing handler i am updating status bar.But that updated status bar is not rendering.Below is a code of handler.

```
    private function fetchAllFilesFromDirectory(f:File):void
    {
        var list:Array=f.getDirectoryListing();
        Application.application.status = "Downloading Local Library..."+list.length+"% Loaded";
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone is still looking for a working code for doing the same here it is:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/31763242/5180320

Answer (score 3):

You're using `getDirectoryListing()` instead of using the async version of the function called `getDirectoryListingAsync()`. The sample on Adobe's website shows how to use it.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.events.FileListEvent;

var directory:File = File.userDirectory;
directory.addEventListener(FileListEvent.DIRECTORY_LISTING, directoryListingHandler);
directory.getDirectoryListingAsync();

function directoryListingHandler(event:FileListEvent):void {
    var list:Array = event.files;
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        trace(list[i].nativePath);
    }
}
```

Do note that even this will not let you show a progress bar because you'll get the entire response in one callback. You can use a spinner instead, which indicates that the application is waiting for a response. Once the callback is triggered, turn off the animation and show the results.